# SwiftUi: Navigating to a secondary page through Button Alert Confirmation

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to figure out how to navigate to my secondary screen through a button alert. Firstly, the user inputs some fields through textfields in the primary screen.

At the bottom of this screen the user presses a submit button which then pops up an alert asking whether they would like to be taken to the secondary screen or cancel to not be taken. All the fields that have been entered through the primary screen then get passed onto the secondary screen. The user than has the option to navigate back to the primary screen if necessary once in the secondary screen.

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
struct View1: View {
    @State var txtField1 : String = ""
    @State var txtField2: String = ""
    @State var txtField3: String = ""
    @State var txtField4: String = ""
    @State var txtField5 : String = ""
   
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var showingView = false

    var body: some View {
    HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Submit")
                            .alert(isPresented:$showingAlert) {
                                Alert(title: Text("Would you like to go to second screen?"), message: Text("The second screen will pass all data from the first screen."), primaryButton:.destructive(Text("Continue")){
                                    self.showingView = true
                                    }, secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel")))
                        }
                    }
                }.popover(isPresented: $showingView){
                    NavigationView{
                        View2(txtField1: self.$txtField1, txtField2: self.$txtField2, txtField3: self.$txtField4, txtField5: self.$txtField5)
                      
                    }

}
```

When using the code above it does navigate to my secondary screen (View2) however its like a sheet. View2 has no navigation properties back to View1 and this is what I'm trying to achieve. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `Back` button you need a `NavigationLink` vs a `popover`. You can just "hide" the `NavigationLink` next to your `Button`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConfirmNavView: View {
    @State var txtField1 : String = ""
    @State var txtField2: String = ""
    @State var txtField3: String = ""
    @State var txtField4: String = ""
    @State var txtField5 : String = ""
    
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var showingView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text("Submit")
                        .alert(isPresented:$showingAlert) {
                            Alert(title: Text("Would you like to go to second screen?"), message: Text("The second screen will pass all data from the first screen."), primaryButton:.destructive(Text("Continue")){
                                self.showingView = true
                            }, secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel")))
                        }
                }
                
                NavigationLink("View2", destination: View2(txtField1: self.$txtField1,
                                                           txtField2: self.$txtField2,
                                                           txtField3: self.$txtField3,
                                                           txtField4: self.$txtField4,
                                                           txtField5: self.$txtField5), isActive: $showingView).hidden().frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
struct View2: View {
    @Binding var txtField1 : String
    @Binding var txtField2: String
    @Binding var txtField3: String
    @Binding var txtField4: String
    @Binding var txtField5 : String
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("txtField1", text: $txtField1)
            TextField("txtField2", text:$txtField2)
            TextField("txtField3", text:$txtField3)
            TextField("txtField4", text:$txtField4)
            TextField("txtField5", text:$txtField5)
        }
    }
}
struct ConfirmNavView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConfirmNavView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity though I initially structured my project having two seperate pages for View 1 and View 2. Do I always have to have a subview in my main view when navigating between pages or can I have two swift pages as well to do this? Let me know your thoughts and thanks!

Comment: A subview? A `NavigationView` usually has a list of some kind and a detail view/ `NavigationLink`. Other options could be a `TabView` or a a `UIKit` page control https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit . Also, if the above code is correct can you "Accept" the answer so I can get credit? Thank you!